# Vue transition animation does not play but keeps its animation duration

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I want to create a simple fade transition for my Vue routes and followed the docs from [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html). Somehow the animations never play but the new content appears immediately. I tried to reproduce it with a fresh project:

- Create a Vue2 project using the Vue router package with the Vue CLI
- Modify the App.vue file to

.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    <transition name="fade">
      <router-view :key="$route.path" />
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  transition: opacity 0;
}
</style>
```

- run the app
- navigate by clicking the links in the navbar

This is a screenshot after clicking on the "About" route in the navbar

[image]

As you can see the content from the "Home" route does not fade out. It just disappears immediately after 2 seconds (value in CSS class). And the content from the "About" route does not fade in, it just appears immediately.

What am I missing?

---

I tried to create a reproducable fiddle to play around with

https://jsfiddle.net/jwuyathp/2/

Navigate around and you will see there is no fade animation.

Comment: If you can recreate this in jsfiddle or something that might help. At first glance it "should" work.

Comment: @MattiPrice yes I created one :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `mode="out-in"`

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <router-view :key="$route.path" />
</transition>
```

And your CSS is wrong. Change it to:

```
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`transition` only says which property to animate. Currently it is animating `opacity` from `1` to `1` (the default value). You need give those properties a different starting/end value:

```
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

Comment: I tried to use your solution and code from the docs, this almost fixes it https://jsfiddle.net/56zqcxvn/1/

Comment: as you can see in the fiddle the animation is still not smooth ... I think the OP is looking for a solution like this https://jsfiddle.net/osw5k0xn/